# Open Source Chatbot for Progress Based web application?

Tags: progress-4gl

What is best possible open source platform for building chatbot? We need to build a chatbot for progess 4gl web application?

Comment: Stackoverflow lends itself best to questions with definite answers rather than a subjective opinion of "what is best". Perhaps you could edit your question to deal with a more specific part of your chatbot?

Answer (score 0):

You are unlikely to find anything that is specifically "for progress 4gl web platform".  The closest is probably going to be Progress' own NativeChat although it's link to OpenEdge is tenuous at best.  The products share a corporate overlord so you might have "one neck to choke" but that's about it.

https://www.progress.com/nativechat/pricing

The 4gl side of things will be equally able to interoperate with anything that uses REST services (or SOAP for that matter).  This might be helpful:

https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-open-source-AI-chatbots-that-use-machine-learning